# What's the difference between canceling a periodic task via the future versus shutting down the executor service the task came from?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, executorservice

Difference between:

A)

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
 ScheduledFuture<> periodicTask = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                doSomething();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Unhandled exception caught whilst doing minutely run", e);
            }
        }, initialDelay, PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// In a shutdown hook:
periodicTask.cancel(true);
```

Does that cancel all the running tasks? Does it kill the ExecutorService?

B) The other way would be:

```
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(....);
```

What's the difference?

Also how do I know how many tasks in the future the executorservice schedules?

Once I get the shut down signal I just want to run my scheduled task around 2 - 3 more times until I reach a certain condition. After that I want to kill it.

Comment: One does a shutdown of the thread pool and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
periodicTask.cancel(true);
```

The cancel method only stops the unstarted jobs and interrupts the running thread which then must return from the run() method.

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

The shutdown() method prevents clients sending more work to the executor service. This means all the existing tasks will run to completion.

```
executorService.awaitTermination(....);
```

This helps the application shut down gracefully. i.e. The executor service takes no more work and waits till all the executing jobs finish and then shuts-down.